# Fill color to gaps of StaggeredGridlayoutManager in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a masonry layout with random colors of sections in the layout. I'm making the layout like this:

[image]

I've used the StaggeredGridLayoutManager and different layout types to make the layout

But I can't fill background color into the gap of StaggeredGridLayoutManager to the same color with other items in Section.

My result:

[image]

Any suggestions how can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it should be a solid color from the top all the way down, then I'd suggest just to set a background color to the specific view type inside your `RecyclerView`'s adapter.

Comment: Oh no, I have many parts and each part will have a different color

Comment: @TrungHau could you please share more info about your current structure then? Is it correct that you're applying `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` to the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @TrungHau because it looks like either it's a separate `RecyclerView` for the section or a `viewType` inside your adapter.
Anyway, I meant to set a background color to the section, whatever container it is.

Comment: Yes @Ruslan Kishai, I'm using StaggeredGridLayoutManager. I want to make this layout: https://i.imgur.com/hClrhvq.png

Comment: @TrungHau again, could you please share your layout structure and adapter? I'd like to figure out if you're using a single `RecyclerView` with different view types or a couple of `RecyclerView`s. Because your parent container has a white background and from the screen, I can see that section uses a separate RecyclerView to display staggered items.
Are you using nested `RecyclerView`s?

Comment: Sorry @Ruslan Kishai, I can't share my layout structure and adapter to you because I have many complex files. I'm using a single RecyclerView with different view types. I have a question for you, how the way to get height of red frame in the picture? (https://i.imgur.com/gVroRWM.jpg)

Comment: If having height, I will create a layout and add this layout into the end. Then I'll set height for this layout equal to the height obtained and same background color.

Comment: Do you think this solution feasible? Or Have you any suggestions how can I do this?

Comment: @TrungHau calculating remaining space is quite a tricky thing, and it's not a reliable solution.
What's stopping you from setting the background color to the view type itself? Your structure is allowing to do that without any side effects related to incorrect measurements.

Comment: Anyway, you can just wait for someone else's solution :) I just see it as the simplest way to resolve the issue without additional computations which can affect app performance in the future.

Comment: Ok, thank you. If I use nested RecyclerView's the bad performance and with nested RecyclerView's can't auto play video for an item contain video when vertical scrolling

Comment: I'm not talking about nested `RecyclerView`s. Sometimes it's required, but not in this case. I just suggested setting the background to the parent which is displaying staggered items. I could show you an example if you'd add to your question at least the part, where you're binding that specific view type and fetching it with items.

Comment: Yes @Ruslan Kishai, got it. Thank you again!